# Problems with Recurrence Relations as a form of Counting

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have been having trouble trying to understand how to do the following problem

> Solve by unfolding: $a_0=3$, and for $n\geq1$, $a_n=5a_{n-1}+3$. Hint: This will involve the geometric sum formula.

---

This is my work so far:
$$a_n=5a_{n-1}+3$$
$$a_n=5(5a_{n-2}+3)+3$$
$$a_n=(5(5(5a_{n-3}+3)+3)+3)$$
$$a_n=5^{n}*a_0+5^{n-1}*3+5^{n-2}*3+...+5*3+3$$
I am not sure if this is right, or how to really do this problem. Help, and hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have some typos because, for example, $\alpha_2$ does not equal that. i guess you meant to write $\alpha_n$ on the left and $\alpha_{n-2}$ on the right

Comment: I don't really know how to go forward with the question. I don't even understand much of my own work there. Happy nd willing to award an answer if one is given, though! @MrFatzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : just noticed that the problem says *solve by unfolding* which is not really smart in my opinion, but I'll leave this answer as this is the way to go with these sequences (arithmetico-geometric).

This is a classic of arithmetico-geometric sequence.
There's a classic formula but there's no need to learn it, you can demonstrate it every time you need it.
$$\text{Let's use }l = \frac{3}{1-5} = -\frac{3}{4}$$
This number is not random, it comes from solving the fixed point of the sequence : $$ l = 5 \times l + 3$$.
Now let's notice this :
$$\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a_{n+1} - l &= 5a_{n} + 3 - l \\
&=5(a_{n}+\frac{3}{5}+\frac{3}{20}) \\
&=5(a_{n}+\frac{15}{20}) \\
&=5(a_{n}-\frac{-3}{4}) \\
&=5(a_{n}-l)
\end{split}
\end{align}$$
We notice that the sequence $b_{n} = a_{n} - l$ is geometric. You can then use your geometric formula to get that : $b_n = 5^n\times b_0$ with $b_0 = 3 -l = \frac{15}{4}$.

Then, problem is solved : $$\begin{align}\begin{split}a_n &= b_n + l\\
&=5^n \times \frac{15}{4} - \frac{3}{4}\\
&= \frac{3}{4}(5^{n+1}-1)
\end{split}\end{align}$$
For further investigation, solve it using the general formula : $u_{n+1} = au_{n} + b$ with the same methodology to find out that : $u_n = a^n(u_0 -l) + l \text{ with } l = \frac{b}{1-a}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Considering $$a_n=5a_{n-1}+3$$ let $a_n=b_n+c$ and replace to get
$$b_n=5 b_{n-1}+4 c+3$$ Now, select the "good" $c$.

Comment: Where did you get the $4c$ from, though?

Comment: $b_n+c=5b_{n-1}+5c+3$

Comment: But why does the $c$ $\neq$ $3$? In what step do we assign a value to $c$?

Comment: @MichaelByrne. What happens if $4c+3=0$ ? Does it start looking familiar to you ?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
a_n
&= 5a_{n-1}+3\\
&= 5(5a_{n-2}+3)+3\\
&= 5^2a_{n-2}+3(5^1+5^0)\\
&= 5^2(5a_{n-3}+3)+3(5^1+5^0)\\
&= 5^3a_{n-3}+3(5^2+5^1+5^0)\\
&= \dots\\
&= 5^na_0+3(5^{n-1}+\dots+5^0)\\
&= 5^n(3)+3\cdot\frac{5^n-1}{5-1}\\
&= 3\cdot5^n+\frac34(5^n-1)\\
&= \frac{15}4\cdot5^n-\frac34\\
&= \frac34(5^{n+1}-1)
\end{align}

Comment: Is that the answer? What's the ... for?

Comment: where did $a_0$ go?

Comment: Oh, I have no clue. This is the question posed. Verbatim from our text.

Comment: @MichaelByrne the full answer is up now

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Lit.

Comment: @MrFatzo $a_0=3$

Comment: oh sorry, I missed that part

Comment: In your final line, why is it not $\frac{3}{4} (5^{n}-1)$

Comment: @MichaelByrne $15=3\cdot5$

Comment: I am referring to the power being $n+1$ instead of $n$

Comment: @MichaelByrne Yes, i know. See the working carefully.

Comment: I don't see use of the geometric sum formula, and I wish there was some work shown for the "..." step. I would b more inclined to award an answer given these two conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your method works great, but you can continue and simplify the result (using the formula for geometric sum):
$$
\alpha_n = 5^n \cdot \alpha_0 + 5^{n-1} \cdot 3 + 5^{n-2} \cdot 3 + ... + 5 \cdot 3 + 3 = \\
5^n\cdot \alpha_0 + 3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}5^k = 5^n \cdot \alpha_0 + 3 (\frac{5^n-1}{5-1})=5^n \cdot \alpha_0 +3\frac{5^n-1}{4}
$$

Comment: For your final bit there, is it $3$ $\frac{5^{n}-1}{4}$ or $3$ $\frac{5^{n+1}-1}{4}$ as suggested above by Karn Watcharasupat?

Comment: It's $5^n$ in my answer. The exponent is the number of terms in the sum and we are going from 0 to $n-1$, which are n terms

Comment: So you and Karn are **both** correct? I appreciate your answer quite a bit. +1 there...but there are two different answers I must consider now.